# Nginx: Grant access by comparing a header value with the contents of a file; possible?

Tags: authentication, nginx, lua

I want to restrict access to some **static** files by comparing a custom header value with for instance an entry in a file. Basically I want to generate such a token in another (restricted) app and have Nginx  deny all requests with non matching headers and header values (the token).

What I've read so far is, that with the [HttpLuaModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) its possible to extend Nginx writing Lua code. But I have no idea if my idea is by any chance working out.

So, is there a simple solution using standard nginx modules (preferred)? Or is installing the Lua module by reinstalling/compiling nginx including the before mentioned module my only chance?

Comment: The ngx_lua module option is your best bet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do this by lua. Check the docs of [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module), as mentioned by aaki. All you need - just insert your logic at getting request phase, such as:

```
location / {
    lua_need_request_body on;

    client_max_body_size 100k;
    client_body_buffer_size 100k;

    access_by_lua '
        -- check the client IP address is in our black list
        if ngx.var.remote_addr == "132.5.72.3" then
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
        end

        -- check if the request body contains bad words
        if ngx.var.request_body and
                 string.match(ngx.var.request_body, "fsck")
        then
            return ngx.redirect("/terms_of_use.html")
        end

        local f = io.open("/tmp/foo")
        local token = f:read("a")
        local user_token = ngx.req.get_headers()["user-session-token"]

        if not user_token or user_token ~= token then
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
        end

        -- tests passed
    ';

    # proxy_pass/fastcgi_pass/etc settings/proceed the request and so on
 }
```

Comment: +1 for the great example. But it does not fully answer my question since it does not show how to check for a header and compare it to a token.

Comment: Ough... here is a full example! :)